# Makefile - SH - Pipelines - errors when trying to run a command

Tags: bash, makefile, cicd

I'm having this issue where my pipeline can't pass and i couldn't figure out what i'm missing.

I created this Makefile, where i call a .sh script this way:

> make init ENV=webapps-dev

```
.PHONY: all
 
DEFAULT_TARGET: all
 
TF_BIN ?= terraform
AWS_REGION ?= us-east-1
 
# AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG: to be able to use shared credentials. Refer to:
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/
TF_VARS = cd environments/$(ENV) && AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
 
TF_ARGS = $(TARGET) 

init:
    utils/plw_utils.sh $(ENV) init
```

This is my sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
set -eo pipefail
 
prepare_deploy_links() {
  local environment=$1
  local raiz=$2
  undo_links $environment
 
  ln -s $raiz/common/provider.tf provider.tf
 
  if [ -f "./.reusables" ]; then
    for tf in $(cat ./.reusables); do
      if [[ $tf == "#"* ]] ; then 
        echo "Excluding ${tf} since it's commented in .reusables"
      else 
        ln -s ../../reusables/$tf .
      fi
    done
  fi
}
 
undo_links() {
  links=$(find . -type l -exec unlink {} \;)
  echo $links
  for file in ${links}; do
    unlink ${file}
  done
}
 
function terraform_get(){        
    rake get_modules[$1]
    terraform get
    # CUR_DIR=$(pwd)
    # cd ..
    # if [ -d "$CUR_DIR" ]; then
    #   cd -
    #   echo "directorio existe $CUR_DIR"
    #   rake get_modules[$1]
    #   terraform get
    # else
    #   echo "no existe $CUR_DIR"
    # fi
 
}
 
function use_terraform() {
    if [ $2 == "apply" ] || [ $2 = "destroy" ]
    then
        terraform $2 -input=false -auto-approve
    elif [ $2 == "init" ]
    then
        terraform_get $1
        terraform $2
 
    elif [ $2 == "get" ]
    then
        terraform_get $1
    else
        terraform $2
    fi
}
 
DIR_RAIZ=$(pwd)
 
cd $DIR_RAIZ/environments/$1
ln -s $DIR_RAIZ/common/provider.tf provider.tf
use_terraform $1 $2
 
for DIR in $DIR_RAIZ/environments/$1/*/; do
    cd $DIR
    # $DIR_RAIZ/utils/plw_utils.sh prepare_deploy_links $DIR $DIR_RAIZ
    prepare_deploy_links $DIR $DIR_RAIZ
    use_terraform $1 $2
done
 
$@
```

When the function terraform_get is called with the uncommented code, this is the error thrown

> Failed to determine current working directory: getwd: no such file or
> directory make: * [Makefile:48: init] Error 1

I tried to check if the directory exists (with the commented code) and i got this error:

> utils/plw_utils.sh: line 85: webapps-dev: command not found make: *
> [Makefile:48: init] Error 127CUR_DIR=$(pwd)

Note that webapps-dev is the content of a variable and not a command itself

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please use code blocks, not quoting, when inserting output: quoting doesn't preserve newlines etc. which makes output hard to read.

Comment: I recommend you add `set -x` to your script and watch what it's doing.  However, I don't really understand what your goal is by adding `$@` at the end of your script; that will try to run the commane `webapps-dev init` which apparently doesn't exist.  I don't understand what the commented code is trying to do.  In any event this isn't a makefile issue; I assume that you'll get the same errors if you run that command from a prompt without a makefile.  I'll point out that your makefile sets a bunch of variables but none of them have any impact on anything because they're not used.